# Configurable products giving error front end. Do not have sub-products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Been working on a new magento 2 site. Been adding new a few additional products which won't show on the website however I get the following error from a product which has been working fine on the site for 2 weeks.

I've attempted to clear the site cache, refresh the index of the site and remove the added products.

```
'Configurable product "Topsoil Supreme" do not have sub-products
#0 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php(43): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver->resolvePrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/AbstractPrice.php(99): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice->getValue()
#2 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php(102): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPrice->getAmount()
#3 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml(24): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->hasSpecialPrice()
#4 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/e...')
#5 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox), '/var/www/html/e...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/e...')
#7 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php(31): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox->_toHtml()
#9 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->_toHtml()
#10 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php(432): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render->render('final_price', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#12 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(297): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getProductPriceHtml(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'final_price', 'item_list', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php(405): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->getProductPriceHtml(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), 'final_price', 'item_list')
#14 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(284): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct->getProductPrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#15 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml(207): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->getProductPrice(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#16 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/e...')
#17 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor), '/var/www/html/e...', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(440): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/e...')
#19 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/html/e...')
#20 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related/Interceptor.php(765): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related\Interceptor->toHtml()
#23 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('catalog.product...')
#24 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.product...')
#25 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('catalog.product...')
#26 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('catalog.product...', true)
#27 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('catalog.product...')
#28 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content.aside')
#29 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content.aside')
#30 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content.aside')
#31 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content.aside', true)
#32 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content.aside')
#33 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#34 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#35 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#36 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#37 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#38 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#39 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#40 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#41 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#42 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#43 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#44 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#45 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#46 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#47 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#48 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#49 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#50 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#51 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#52 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#53 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#54 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#55 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#56 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#57 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#58 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#59 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#60 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#61 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#62 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#63 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#64 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#65 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#66 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#67 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#69 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#70 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#71 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#73 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#74 /var/www/html/earthcycle/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#75 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#76 /var/www/html/earthcycle/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#77 /var/www/html/earthcycle/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#78 {main}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the product price set to 0 try to change it to 1.

Please refer to this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3912

Answer (score 0):

Just another bug in the Magento2, there's no mention if Magento is tracking this privately on their secret issue tracker, but in meantime apply this patch  (presuming your off develop branch) https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/7030 to get going.